# can there be multiple instances of the same (Open)JPA entity in an application? Equals does not work for Entity Instances?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entity, openjpa

Our stack: Tomcat 7, Spring 3.1.1, OpenJPA 2.2.0

I came accross an issue, the root was a comparisson:

```
server1.equals(server2);
```

server1 and server2 are both instances of the Entity "Server":

```
@Entity
public class Server implements Serializable {
   private long id;
   // getters and setters
}
```

I had to change the comparisson to:

```
server1.getId().equals(server2.getId());
```

That one worked, the above one returns false, even if the id of the servers are the same.
I also checked the hashCodes of the two instances, the two instances had indeed a different hashCode.

Why are there two instances of the same entity in our application?

How can that happen? There is only one entity of the "Server" in the database.

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: where is the `@Transactional` annotation located (at the DAO?), please post the code that shows how you load the entities and how you compare them.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/data/basic/dao/ServerDao.java?view=markup is the Dao that loads the entities. The comparison is like in the above method. But the code of the comparison is in http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/conference/room/ClientListHashMapStore.java?view=markup line 487, if you replace that entry.getValue().getServer().equals(server) you will never get true, you always need to compare based on Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have multiple instance of Entiry if it is different session or outside session. In your case you are doing comparison in `ClientListHashMapStore` that is not part of transaction. That means there is no session and you will have multiple instances of Entity. Ideally one should override `equals` method if comparison of two instances is required.

Answer (score 4):

There will be different instances if you load them with different entity managers or different transactions for example.

Comment: BTW: have a look at: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html

Comment: There is only one EntityManager. There is also only one ServerDao that is annotated as @Transactional.

Comment: @seba.wagner: I do not fully understand your `ClientListHashMapStore` implmentation, but if only DAO has a `@Transaction` annotation (and you use no OpenEntityManagerInView Filter) you have two transactions if you invoke two different Dao methods!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you have 2 (at least) class loaders in your application. One loads Entity and then instance server1 is created and the second loads server2. Usually these are managed internally by your technology stack

This is correct in general in java and not only in your particular application.
Now the tricky part is where are these class loaders are coming from.

First of all in order to ensure that this is the case you can try to print out the class loaders, something like this:

```
print before comparison: server1.getClass().getClassLoader()
print before comparison: server2.getClass().getClassLoader()
```

This can give you an idea of what happens there.
It may come from different deployment units for example.

Hope this helps